# Windows 10 modern-ui apps wrong language

Tags: windows, language, modern-ui, windows-10

I've installed Windows 10 official release (not the preview) from Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 and I've some problems with the language. 
My OS is in French but all my modern-ui apps (weather, store, calendar,...) are in English. I've W10 Professional and I precise that when I had W7, I had to set default language to French after the installation (this was an english version of Windows).
Have you some ideas ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've solved my problem by putting in the languages settings the French language at the top. After some restarts all my modern ui apps are in French.

Comment: It looks like orders matters (i.e. first language not supported by application, take second, if not supported take third...)

Comment: Very helpful answer.  Who would have guessed that a presented Languages choice of English (Canada) would be invalid?  My Windows 10 Pro (Version: 1607, OS Build: 14393.351) Modern Apps defaulted to the next language on the list, so had to make that English (United States) to get an english "skin" for the Modern Apps.

Answer (score 10):

Registered just to post this, hope it helps others who got fustrated with it as well.

Under Control Panel > Language > Advanced Settings > Override for Windows display language

Defaults follows your language setup, you can choose to select what language you wan't to show here.

Answer (score 2):

It's a late answer, but when I had the same problem I solved it very quickly and easily.
I live in Germany and love my OS to be in English. In order to achieve a full English OS, including apps, and a German keyboard layout I went into my locale settings (**Settings** => **Time & Language** => **Region & Language**) and first off moved English (which was set to override the OS language) to the top. Then I clicked on English, clicked on **Options** and directly clicked on **Add a keyboard** and selected the German keyboard layout. After that was set I removed the US keyboard layout and then had Windows 10 displaying in English, including all of the apps, with a German keyboard layout.

I hope this answer alone might help or would give you some options to look after.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I did not set my default language as the one that I wanted Windows 10 apps to be in.

For Windows 10 users:

Settings > Time & language > Region & language > Click the language that you want it to be default > Set as default

Then after you restart the Windows 10 app, it should use the default language setting.