# Changing display language in Windows 10 creates mashup of two languages

Tags: windows-10, language

I just installed Windows 10 Home in Swedish, then went to set the display language to English. It worked for most of the operating system, but lots of Windows apps and things are still in Swedish. What can I do to display everything in English? I do not want to go back to the original language, but rather completely remove its presence and only use English.

[image: Mish mash example]

Comment: I'm now making a Windows 10 Setup USB with the English version, which I'm downloading from the Microsoft website, and I'll try using my current license key to install it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 modern-ui apps wrong language](http://superuser.com/questions/946789/windows-10-modern-ui-apps-wrong-language)

Comment: You don't need to enter your product key.  Windows 10 automatically activates itself

Comment: I tried the things in that post already, but the problem remained.

Comment: Well, now I did a full reformat so I entered the key again - wanted to make sure there was no trace of the old installation left.

Comment: Perhaps the difference between this question and the duplicate suggestion is that in that question the goal was to return to the originally installed language, whereas my desire was to move completely to the newly installed language. In the end it was the same problem, but I followed those steps to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually what I did was to download the English installer from Microsoft's website and reinstall the entire OS, formatting the disk. Might have been an overkill, but at least it solved the problem. My serial key came from a Swedish installation, but I had no issues using it for the English installation.